# ¿Cómo crear un objeto Date con hora del sistema en javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

tengo una *async function* que se ejecuta cada que se oprime un botón "Update".

Declaro un variable que controle la fecha (tomada desde un formulario) para poder guardarla en base de datos.

El "problema" es que la primera vez que hago click en Update, la variable se crea correctamente con fecha y hora del sistema, sin embargo si hago un segundo Update, la variable se crea con fecha del sistema pero con time "00:00:00.000Z"

Código:

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {

      //...Validaciones y otro código aquí

      const statusDate = new Date(req.body.date);
      console.log(statusDate);
}
```

Salida en consola:

```
Primera vez: 2021-08-24T09:29:33.830Z
Segunda y demás veces en adelante: 2021-08-24T00:00:00.000Z
```

Comment: `new Date()` devuelve un objeto `Date` con la fecha y hora actual del sistema. Si por alguna razón eso no te vale, podrías quizá usar `Date.now()`, que devuelve el nº de ms pasados desde el 1 de enero de 1970. Algo así `new Date(Date.now())` te devolvería la fecha y hora actual (pero vamos, debería funcionar el constructor sin ningún parámetro).

Answer (score 1):

Si creas un nuevo objeto `Date`, sin parámetros, te devuelve la [fecha y hora actuales del sistema](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#parameters): `new Date()`

Si eso no te funcionara por alguna razón, `Date.now()` te devuelve el número de milisegundos desde el 1 de enero de 1970, puedes pasarle eso al constructor y te dará la hora actual también: `new Date(Date.now())`. Pero esto no debería hacerte falta.

```js
function imprimirFecha() {
  console.log(new Date());
}

setInterval(imprimirFecha, 1000);
```

Comment: Gracias @ArianJM.
¿Es normal que la hora me la este dando con 5 horas adicionales a la que tengo en sistema? es decir, al ejecutar tu código la hora es: 15:03.

Comment: @IsaacJiménez eerrrrr, no sé, quizá esté dando la hora en otro huso horario. A mí, ejecutarlo aquí en Stack Overflow me da la hora en GMT, pero si lo hago en la consola del navegador, me da la hora en GMT+2 (que es donde estoy).